# failed to link simple code

Tags: c++, linker

i have this simple code in the following files:

Stat.h

```
#ifndef STAT_H
#define STAT_H

class Stat {
    public:
        void compute_value();
};

#endif
```

Stat.cpp

```
class Stat {
    public:
        void compute_value() {
        }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Stat.h"

int main(void)
{
    Stat stat;
    stat.compute_value();
}
```

When i try to compile i got the following error:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weverything -O3 Stat.cpp main.cpp -o main
/tmp/main-0466d7.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf6a): undefined reference to `Stat::compute_value()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redefining the class in your *Stat.cpp* source file because definition is also a declaration. Instead of having the entire class redefinition you only need to define the member function(s) in your *Stat.cpp* source file and include the *Stat.h* header:

```
#include "Stat.h"

void Stat::compute_value() {}
```